# force spinning symbol for loading applications in MATE

Tags: icons, mate

On MATE under 20.04.1 LTS (as well as previous LTS releases that I have tried), the GUI arrow (on-screen activation pointer) that one positions over a desktop icon for an executable application becomes a small circular spinning icon whilst the application is "loading" but not yet visible on the screen for SOME applications, but not all.  Is there a setting that will force the spinning or other waiting/loading icon to appear as an application initiates?  I suspect that this behavior is common to all of the Ubuntu GUI windowing environments.  I note that under EL (not LTS) for all the major releases I have used, either with MATE, "old" Gnome, or "old" KDE, an equivalent waiting icon was shown for all applications that were selected for use but not yet "loaded".

Comment: I would recommend to ask also on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ for more productive discussion.